# How can I optimize the conversion of a Data Frame to Map[String,List[String]] in scala/spark?

Tags: scala, apache-spark-sql

I have a DataFrame with a lot of Signals and I want to convert it into a Map[String, List[String]]

I have running Code, but I have the problem that it takes very long to execute it. For only a bunch of hundred signals it needs about 13 minutes.

This is the inputDataFrame I got in the beginning (example):

```
+----------+-----+
|SignalName|Value|
+----------+-----+
|        S1|   V1|
|        S2|   V1|
|        S1|   V2|
|        S2|   V2|
|        S3|   V1|
|        S1|   V3|
|        S1|   V1|
+----------+-----+
```

Then I want to filter the duplicates

```
var reducedDF = inputDataFrame.select("SignalName","Value").dropDuplicates()
```

The ouput for reduedDF.show :

```
+----------+-----+
|SignalName|Value|
+----------+-----+
|        S1|   V1|
|        S1|   V2|
|        S1|   V3|
|        S2|   V1|
|        S2|   V2|
|        S3|   V1|
+----------+-----+
```

The next step is to get an RDD of SignalNames without an duplicate. And I used zipWithIndex(), because later I want to read every value of the RDD.
I can do this with the following code:

```
var RDDOfSignalNames = reducedDF.select("SignalName").rdd.map(r => r(0).asInstanceOf[String])  
RDDOfSignalNames = RDDOfSignalNames.distinct() 
val RDDwithIndex = RDDOfSignalNames.zipWithIndex() 
val indexKey = RDDwithIndex.map { case (k, v) => (v, k) }
```

And now the last step is to get for every SignalName every possible Value as a List of Type List[String] and add it to an Map:

```
var dataTmp: DataFrame = null
var signalname = Seq[String]("")
var map = scala.collection.mutable.Map[String, List[String]]()

for (i <- 0 to (RDDOfSignalNames.count()).toInt - 1) {

  signalname = indexKey.lookup(i)

  dataTmp = reducedDF.filter(data.col("Signalname").contains(signalname(0)))          

  map += (signalname(0) -> dataTmp.rdd.map(r => r(0).asInstanceOf[String]).collect().toList) 
  println(i+"/"+(RDDOfSignalNames.count().toInt - 1).toString())

}
```

In the End the Map looks like this:

```
scala.collection.mutable.Map[String,List[String]] = Map(S1 -> List(V1, V2, V3), S3 -> List(V1), S2 -> List(V1, V2))
```

The Problem is the line map += ... for 106 Signals it takes about 13 minutes! Is there more efficient way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, use of `var` is not recommended in *scala*. You should always try to use *immutable variables*. So changing the following line

```
var reducedDF = inputDataFrame.select("SignalName","Value").dropDuplicates()
```

to

```
val reducedDF = inputDataFrame.select("SignalName","Value").distinct()
```

is preferred.

**And**,

You don't need to go through such complexities to get your desired output. You can get your desired output doing the following

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.collect_list
reducedDF
      .groupBy("SignalName")
      .agg(collect_list($"Value").as("Value"))
      .rdd
      .map(row => (row(0).toString -> row(1).asInstanceOf[scala.collection.mutable.WrappedArray[String]].toList))
      .collectAsMap()
```

where,
`reducedDF.groupBy("SignalName").agg(collect_list($"Value").as("Value"))` gives you `dataframe` as

```
+----------+------------+
|SignalName|Value       |
+----------+------------+
|S3        |[V1]        |
|S2        |[V2, V1]    |
|S1        |[V1, V2, V3]|
+----------+------------+
```

the rest of the code `.rdd.map(row => (row(0).toString -> row(1).asInstanceOf[scala.collection.mutable.WrappedArray[String]].toList)).collectAsMap()` is just converting the `dataframe` to your desired output `Map`.

final map output is

```
Map(S1 -> List(V1, V2, V3), S3 -> List(V1), S2 -> List(V2, V1))
```

Comment: Now I got the Error Message:
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: undefined function collect_list;

Comment: did you import `import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.collect_list`?

Comment: Yes i did it, but i use spark 1.6.2! I think there is the problem

Comment: did you do `import sqlContext.implicits._`? If no, you will have to do that. If yes please go throught https://wwija.com/computer-internet-technology/2631091_use-collect-list-and-collect-set-in-spark-sql.html

Comment: yes I also imported `sqlContext.implicits._` but still I have the Error!
I saw this page before but it doesn`t help me a lot because I have a Spark Version < 2.0

Comment: why don't you try `collect_list(col("Value")).as("Value")` in the agg part? for this you would need `import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._`. If that too gives error try  `collect_list(reducedDF("Value")).as("Value")`

Comment: The code works now in the Spark-Shell but not when I upload a jar to the cluster. Do you have any other ideas?

Comment: do you have spark jars in the cluster?

Comment: I have these spark jars all with version 1.6.2: 1. `spark-core-2.10` 2.`spark-hive_2.10`3.`spark-mllib_2.10`4. `spark-sql_2.10`  and when I add the dependencys i always add `<scope>provided</scope>` in case there is already a verison on the cluster!

Comment: don't put provided in spark-sql and try .:)

Comment: No, it is still not working :(  Still the line with the collect_list throws the Exception